# Overfull \hbox in the Table of Figures when using custom page numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I use a custom page numbering for appendices:

```
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{A~--~\arabic{page}}
```

The problem is there is a overfull \hbox in the Table of Figures for the custom page numbering:

[image: The page numbering for appendix ceate an overfull hbox]

The problem does not appear in the Table of Contents, so I am really wondering why it happens and what can I do to prevent it ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How did you remove the chapters' starting page numbers from the toc, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to increase the width of the box used to typeset page numbers in the `toc`, `lot` and `lof` etc since `A - 1` is not fitting in (it protrudes in to the right margin in your figure). The following diagram is useful.

[image]

Here `\@pnumwidth` is the width of the box where page numbers are typeset. Note that `\@tocrmarg` should be greater than `\@pnumwidth` for otherwise, the dots will hit the page number in toc.

You can change `\@tocrmarg` and `\@pnumwidth` by adding these in your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
  \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{4em}
\makeatother
```

As an alternative, you can use `tocloft` package and add these in your preamble

```
\cftsetpnumwidth{3em}
\cftsetrmarg{4em}  %% make sure that this is larger than above
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

%% without packages
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
  \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{4em}
\makeatother
%% with tocloft
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\cftsetpnumwidth{3em}
%\cftsetrmarg{4em}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\setcounter{page}{1000}
\chapter{Some}
\section{some}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{some figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working perfectly! Very complete answer by the way, thanks again !

Comment: @Harish Your solution works great, but it 'messes up' the list of tables and list of figures. Could you please tell me, how to use the settings **only** for the table content? Thank you very much!

Comment: @BBerry What do you mean by `table content`? Is it `list of tables`?

Comment: @Harish Sorry for the confusion, I meant the `\tableofcontents`